# How to fix Uncaught TypeError in Phaser 3 for Game Development

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm following a space shooter tutorial for a game I'm developing as I learn Javascript. The tutorial puts many of the classes in the same file stacked on top of each other, but I've read this isn't a good practice and all Classes should have their own separate file. The link for the tutorial is here...

https://yorkcs.com/2019/02/08/build-a-space-shooter-with-phaser-3-4/

I've made sure everything is typed properly, but whenever I run it in Chrome (and I've cleared my cache too), I get an error message that says...

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFirstTick' of null**

It's throwing the error on line 21 of enemies.js for this line of code...

```
this.play( 'basicenemy' );
```

I've tried several things because I've gotten different errors. I think I've made the mistake of following separate tutorials. I've tried adding the images to the files themselves instead of the sceneMain.js file where the first level is because at one point it was telling me that play() was undefined.

**entities.js**

```
class Entities extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite
{
  constructor(scene, x, y, key, type)
  {
    super(scene, x, y, key, type);
    this.scene = scene;
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.scene.physics.world.enableBody(this, 0);
    this.setData("type", type);
    this.setData("isDead", false);
  }
}
```

**enemies.js**

```
class BasicEnemy extends Entities
{
  constructor(scene, x, y)
  {
    super(scene, x, y, 'basicenemy', 'BasicEnemy');
    this.body.velocity.y = Phaser.Math.Between(50, 100);
    this.shootTimer = this.scene.time.addEvent({
        delay: 1000,
        callback: function() {
          var laser = new EnemyLaser(
            this.scene,
            this.x,
            this.y
          );
          laser.setScale(this.scaleX);
          this.scene.enemyLasers.add(laser);
        },
        callbackScope: this,
        loop: true
      });
    this.play( 'basicenemy' );
  }
}
```

**sceneMain.js**

```
//The Bullet Group
    this.basicEnemy = this.add.group();
    this.enemyLasers = this.add.group();
    this.playerLasers = this.add.group();

    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 100,
        callback: function() {
          var enemy = new BasicEnemy(
            this,
            Phaser.Math.Between(0, this.game.config.width),
            0
          );
          this.basicEnemy.add(enemy);
        },
        callbackScope: this,
        loop: true
      });
```

In **sceneMain.js** I'm trying to get enemies to spawn from the top of the screen with this line...

```
this.basicEnemy.add(enemy);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a lot of things to say on this way of coding but it follows a logic that is more related to ES6 syntax which is the actual aim of the Phaser framework, so I have a first question which is what do you want to do by calling `this.play('basicenemy');` ofc I guess it's to play an animation but can you just tell me that so we can dig more on the way you're coding your game

Comment: It was advised that I don't post an entire file and only parts, but this is the entire sceneMain.js file. I'm not entirely sure what getFirstTick is referring to. The goal is to get a series of animations to play. I have some static images already set and a scrolling background as you can see below.

Comment: Now that I look back at the tutorial though, the author doesn't say **this.play()** is meant for animations though, I believe he just has static sprites spawning from the top of the game map. That could be the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SceneMain extends Phaser.Scene 
{
constructor() 
{
    super('SceneMain');

}
preload()
//loads our images and sounds
{
    //this.load.image( "playership","images/blueship.png" );
    this.load.image( 'spaceback4','images/spaceback4.png' );
    this.load.spritesheet( 'blueships', 'images/blueships.png', { frameWidth: 73, frameHeight: 80 });
    this.load.spritesheet( 'blueshot', 'images/blueshipshot.png', { frameWidth: 20, frameHeight: 55 });
    this.load.spritesheet( 'basicenemy', 'images/basicenemy.png', { frameWidth: 65, frameHeight: 80 });

    this.load.audio( 'explosion', 'audio/explosion.mp3' );
    this.load.audio( 'laser', 'audio/lasershot.mp3' );
    this.load.audio( 'enemylaser', 'audio/enemylaser.mp3' );

}
create()
//define our objects 
{
    //The Starfield Background
    this.starfield = this.add.tileSprite( 0, 0, 1080, 900, "spaceback4" );   

    //The Grid System
    var gridConfig={ row:5, cols:5, scene:this };
    var alignGrid = new AlignGrid( gridConfig );
    //alignGrid.showNumbers();

    //The Score
    this.sb = new ScoreBox( {scene:this} );
    alignGrid.placeAtIndex( 2, this.sb );
    model.score = 0; 


    //The Player Ship
    this.playerShip = this.physics.add.sprite( 0,0, 'blueships' );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'fly',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames( 'blueships', {start: 0, end: 9 }),
        frameRate: 16,
        repeat: -1
    });
    this.playerShip.play( 'fly', this );
    alignGrid.placeAtIndex( 22, this.playerShip );
    this.playerShip.setCollideWorldBounds( true );

    //The Enemy Ships
    this.basicEnemy = this.physics.add.sprite( 0,0, 'basicenemy' )
    this.basicEnemy2 = this.physics.add.sprite( 0,0, 'basicenemy' )
    this.basicEnemy3 = this.physics.add.sprite( 0,0, 'basicenemy' )

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'badfly',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNames( 'basicenemy', {start: 0, end: 9 }),
        frameRate: 16,
        repeat: -1
    });
    this.basicEnemy.play( 'badfly', this );
    this.basicEnemy2.play( 'badfly', this );
    this.basicEnemy3.play( 'badfly', this );
    alignGrid.placeAtIndex( 6, this.basicEnemy );
    alignGrid.placeAtIndex( 7, this.basicEnemy2 );
    alignGrid.placeAtIndex( 8, this.basicEnemy3 );

    //The Bullet Group
    this.basicEnemy = this.add.group();
    this.enemyLasers = this.add.group();
    this.playerLasers = this.add.group();

    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 100,
        callback: function() {
          var enemy = new BasicEnemy(
            this,
            Phaser.Math.Between(0, this.game.config.width),
            0
          );
          this.basicEnemy.add(enemy);
        },
        callbackScope: this,
        loop: true
      });

    //The Audio
    this.sfx = {
        laser: [
          this.sound.add( 'laser' ),
          this.sound.add( 'enemylaser' )
        ],
        explosion: this.sound.add( 'explosion' )
      };

    //The Starfield
    alignGrid.placeAtIndex( 12, this.starfield );

    //Controls
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    this.fireButton = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.SPACE);

}
update()
//constant running loops 
{
    //Scroll the starfield
    this.starfield.tilePositionY += -1.5;

    //Player Movement
    this.playerShip.setAccelerationX( 0 );
    this.playerShip.setDragX( 300 );


    if (this.cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        this.playerShip.setAccelerationX (-300 );
    }
    if (this.cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        this.playerShip.setAccelerationX ( 300 );
    }

    //  Fire bullet
    /*if (this.fireButton.isDown || this.input.activePointer.isDown) 
    {
        this.fireBullet();
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG I got it to work!!! I simply removed **this.play()** from enemies.js and added it to sceneMain.js. This is the new code that works! For some reason it didn't want to play from the Enemies class, but it plays in sceneMain. I figured I would just use the code that already worked to spawn three static enemies that didn't move and would use it to spawn the enemies that drop from the top that the tutorial shows. Now I have enemies that are stationary and enemies that spawn and shoot bullets!

```
//The Enemies and Bullet Group That Spawns from the Top
    this.basicEnemy = this.add.group();
    this.enemyLasers = this.add.group();
    this.playerLasers = this.add.group();

    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 100,
        callback: function() 
        {
          var enemy = new BasicEnemy( this, Phaser.Math.Between(0, this.game.config.width), 0 );
          this.basicEnemy = this.physics.add.sprite(enemy);
          this.basicEnemy.play( 'badfly', this);
        },
        callbackScope: this,
        loop: true
      });
```

Comment: Nice to see it fixed, happy coding Brian :)